# Three.js changing camera lookat with click of button

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'd like to change the camera `lookat` position when clicking a button or link. Here's my code:

HTML:

```
 <a href="#" id="testButton">TEST</a>
```

JS:

```
render();
function render() {
    trackballControls.update(60);
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    webGLRenderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// test button function
// this does not work
var testButton = document.getElementById('testButton');
testButton.onclick = function ()
{
     camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(50,60,70));
}; 

// another test button function
// this does work but then the camera bounces back to what it was looking at before
var testButton2 = document.getElementById('testButton');
testButton2.onclick = function ()
{
     camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(50,60,70));
     webGLRenderer.render(scene, camera);
};
```

What am I doing wrong? [Here is the test page](http://jay2.ligda.net/3Dtest/stackoverflow3.html) (wait for Eiffel Tower to load).

Comment: You need to set `controls.target` instead. Look at the `TrackballControls.update()` source code.

Comment: Thanks!  With a little tweaking I was able to get this to work!

Comment: Except I can't mark this as solved because it looks like you answered with a comment.

Comment: OK, I added an answer for you to accept. :-)

Answer (score 7):

For `OrbitControls` and `TrackballControls`, the camera "looks at" `controls.target`, which is a `THREE.Vector3()`.

To change the target use this pattern:

```
controls.target.set( x, y, z );
```

three.js r.67